# Android NDK: Infinite Loop Not Being Called Infinitely

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm writing a utility for Android using the NDK.

In my utility, I fork a process and in that process, I run the following code:

```
//Screenshot thread
int i = 0;
for (;;) {
  char filename[255];
  snprintf(filename, sizeof(filename),
    "/data/local/screenshots/screen%d.png", i);
  execlp("screencap", "screencap", "-p", filename, NULL);
  i++;
  sleep(500);
}
```

I'm finding  that the screenshot is created the *first* time, but subsequent screenshots aren't taken. When I stop the program, I find that I have a `screen0.png` file, but no `screen1.png` or any subsequent files. I've made sure to read up on the docs and it appears that the Android [sleep](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) function takes a millisecond argument.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [`execve(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) manual page

> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> The `exec()` functions return only if an error has occurred. The return value is -1, and errno is set to indicate the error.

So the loop is blocked at the `exec()` call and stays there unless an error occurs.

Comment: Does that matter to this question? It's just the way it's specified by POSIX. And surely there are good reasons for it.

Comment: @njzk2 `exec` overwrites the current program with a different one, in the same process. It does not create a new process.

Comment: @njzk2 because are some legitimate use cases for `fork()` without `exec()`. Vice versa, too.